# Unable to reinstall split APKs with adb

Tags: android, installation, apk, adb

I currently cannot manage to reinstall any Android app that is using AABs/Split APKs by executing `adb install-multiple -r *.apk`.
This has been working before, but now always gives me `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install com.reddit.frontpage without first uninstalling.]`.

Manually uninstalling and using adb to newly install the app is working. However, this is annoying as I might also lose quite some app data. This problem concerns two of my Android devices (Tablet with 7.1 and Phone with 6.0) and also a wide range of apps. Also installation and reinstallation of standalone APKs is working flawlessly.

Is there a current issue with install-multiple -r or does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

So, I managed to figure out a temporary workaround.

1. Manually uninstall the concerned app with `adb shell pm uninstall -k <package-name>`. The `-k` flag makes sure that the app's data is being kept.
2. Install app again with `adb install-multiple *.apk`.